# Is there a Hiveql function using which we can pull records from a table where a JSON type column has a specific value for a key?

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-query

I'm looking to get count of records in which a column(type) of json type has certain key:value in table named product_type.

```
_______________________________________________________
id  |   product |            type                     |

1    | product_1  | {"costly": true, "l_type": true}  |
2    | product_2  | {"costly": false, "l_type": true} |
3    | product_3  | {"costly": false, "l_type": true} |
4    | product_4  | {"costly": false, "l_type": true} |
_______________________________________________________
```

Something like-

```
select count(id) from product_table where type has {"costly": false}
```

What I have tried:

```
select count(*) from product_table where type LIKE '%"costly": false%'
```

-> which is not yielding any results.

Expecting to get:
3 ( as there are 3 records that has value as false in type column for the key costly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved:

```
select count(*) from product_table where get_json_object(type,$.costly) is true;
```